# How to print a red left middle bracket '[' in console in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, colors, console.log

I want to print a red '[' in the option, but I face an error.

```
program
  .option('\x1b[31m--bcc [string]', 'bcc email address.');
```

When I remove the '[', it ran successfully. Does anyone know how to print it?

Comment: What is `program.option` and what is the expected output of this code?

Comment: Because if I do `console.log('\x1b\[31m--bcc [string]')` it prints `--bcc [string]` in red, which is what I expect it to do ...

Comment: ```program.option``` is a function of a package in node.js called commander, which can be used to write command line.
https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-a-cli-tool-with-node-js/

Comment: Hm, the parameters of that `option` call are not just the strings that are printed to the console, they are also a definition of what the progam expects as commandline parameter, so using escape sequences probably isn't such a great idea after all ...